# Failed review audit on question that was edited for clarity but still closed

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

I failed [this audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/21290454) because I marked a clear question as `Leave Open`.

The comments on the question indicate that it was edited while several people were still voting to close it.

Given what I can see about the question on the review audit screen, was my thought process incorrect? What should I have done better?

Comment: That question, even with the improved title provided by the editor, is not particularly clear to me. Is it perfectly clear to you?

Comment: The question doesn't even state what the problem is. Unclear seems to be a good close reason.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you let yourself be misguided by the comments on the question.

Even with the "improved" title, the question is quite incomplete and unclear.

Do they have a problem with the code provided? They need to know how to read user input? If so, in which way is computing the division relevant? Or they also need help on how to perform the arithmetic?

If you read the accepted answer, it evens begins with *"I don't know what exactly you want"*. Not exactly a ringing endorsement.

It's fine to pay attention to the comments in a question for additional context, but you should judge the post on its own merits. (In this case, the comments and edit came **before** the question was closed, so they weren't particularly relevant to the case).

Comment: Thanks for the advice, will do. Any idea why this question was downvoted so much?

Comment: Votes in meta are often used to express agreement/disagreement with a post.